# How to download bond issuer information for MILLIONS of CUSIPs from Bloomberg API?

Tags: api, finance, bloomberg

I now have a project which needs me to obtain the issuer information (issuer names & ultimate borrowers) for several millions of bonds (mostly municipal bonds)...Is there a way to do that from Bloomberg? Would it work if I used the Python API? Or are there any other data providers that I could use?

I heard Bloomberg has a monthly limit of number of securities you can download, like 5000 securities? Is that the same for municipal bonds too?
I have hit the N/A Review error before so I know it's a lot of pain to sort it out... Don't really wanna risk it again haha.
I have explored getting these data elsewhere, like from Refinitiv Loan Connector and municipalbonds.com, but to no avail.

Comment: The limit is more than 5,000 but certainly less than 1,000,000. You could use the Bloomberg Data Licence (but it is not free).

Comment: You can technically do it in bql but you’d have to break it into multiple queries because bql also has limits of how many results can be returned, but I bet you’d blow out the data limit. I’d talk to your account rep and explain: it’s better to have their blessing for after you hit NA Review. 

I think any of the big players have similiar limits. 

Can you get what you need from SRCH or something?

Comment: What are you intending to do with the information? I doubt you are producing a report with `millions` of rows. If you are aggregating it in some way (eg by country, industry sector etc) then perhaps look at BQL which can do the aggregation on the server side before the data comes to you.